# Why app redux have error in this reducer?

Tags: javascript

Why app redux have error in this reducer? what have I not done? and where exactly?how to fix it? Tell me please Tell me please
reducer:

```
import { searchFilter } from '../components/app';
     function reducer (state = {}, action) {

        switch (action.type) {
          case 'SET_SHIFT':
             return Object.assign({} {
                shift: action.shift
             });
          case 'SET_SEARCH':
             return Object.assign({} {
                search: action.search.toLowerCase()
             });
          case 'RUN_FILTER':
             return Object.assign({} {
                shift: action.shift || state.shift,
                search: action.search || state.search,
                filteredData: searchFilter(state.search, state.data[state.shift])
             });
          case 'LOAD_DATA_START':
             return Object.assign({}{
                day: action.day
             });
          case 'LOAD_DATA_END':
             return Object.assign({} {
                data: action.data,
                shift: Object.keys(action.data)[0],
                filteredData: searchFilter(state.search, state.data[state.shift])
             });
       }
    }

    export default reducer;
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: One problem I see right now is that a reducer should be a pure function which takes the old state and creates a new state from it. It then returns the new state (see the [docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions)). Your reducer does not return anything and the switch is missing a `default` case.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: @TomasGidnop Note that to return something from a function, you need to have a `return` statement.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on in your example, I'd strip it back a bit (especially getting rid of middleware and thunk), get a handle on the basic Redux model and then build it out again.

Your reducer should look something like this:

```
 import { searchFilter } from '../components/app';
 function reducer (state = {}, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SET_SHIFT':
         //no need for break on return
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
            shift: action.shift
         });
      case 'SET_SEARCH':
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
            search: action.search.toLowerCase()
         });
      case 'RUN_FILTER':
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
            shift: action.shift || state.shift,
            search: action.search || state.search,
            filteredData: searchFilter(state.search, state.data[state.shift])
         });
      case 'LOAD_DATA_START':
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
            day: action.day
         });
      case 'LOAD_DATA_END':
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
            data: action.data,
            shift: Object.keys(action.data)[0],
            filteredData: searchFilter(state.search, state.data[state.shift])
         });
      //then you definitely need to have this
      default:
         return state;
   }
}

export default reducer;
```

Can I recommend you put some console.log statements in your reducer so you can see the data is being put into the Redux store as expected?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Just pasted in your code. Corrected now. As you're defining the state object's properties, no semi-colons and no equals signs! Just commas if more than one property

Comment: Yes, another copy and paste bug. You obviously don't want any reference to state in the object passed into object assign. Try now

Comment: OK I'll try to have a look

Comment: I had a look and it's just going to take too long to sort everything out. Sorry. Just take stuff out until you get to a model that works, then start putting stuff back in. That's the best I can do for you.

Comment: And read this several times - https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/

Comment: Yes I'm short of time. You had a working version without Redux - revert back to that - then read the article and move one piece of data, just one, out of state and into redux, then try and make that work. The problem is you're losing track of what's causing the errors.

Comment: I've just looked at your previous version without redux

Comment: And you will not find it takes too long if you go back to that, read the article and start again

Comment: Np problem. Good luck. Just go back to the version without Redux, then try to just move one piece of data at a time into Redux, check it works, and on you go.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see is you do not return the new state from your reducer.

A reducer should be a pure function wich, given a state and an action, returns a new state.

put `return state` at the bottom of your reducer.